# Set page's top margin when sending to pinter ZPL-II via TcpClient

Tags: c#, vb.net, printing, zpl, zpl-ii

I have following code which sends data to printer and prints page. I want somehow to tell th printer the top margin of the page. Is there anyway i could do that with current code? The printer is Zebra and uses ZPL-II.

```
Dim data As String = "path to file"
Dim client As New TcpClient()
client.Connect(IPadressDrukarki, 8569)
Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
Dim sendBytes As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(data)
stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
stream.Close(9000)
client.Close()
```

**EDIT:**
Will this print out top margin of 100 dots?

```
Dim data As String = "^XA^LH0,100^XZ some text"
```

Answer (score 2):

`^LHx,y` (Label Home) allows defining the upper-left corner of the label format.  It is best to include it in the label definition (typically right after the `^XA`), but it can also be sent separately.  For example, if you want to move the printing down 100 dots, you could send `^XA^LH0,100^XZ` to the printer prior to sending the actual label format.

Additional response to questions asked by the OP.

Your code is a little confusing because you appear to be using the term `some text` to mean an actual file path(?).  And  `IO.File.ReadAllBytes(data)` then reads in the file, which we must assume is a ZPL label format.

So to answer your question then yes, just insert `^XA^LH0,100^XZ` before the file contents of `some text` when sending to the printer.

Comment: so based on my example if I want to make top margin 100 dots should I set my string as I shown in main post's edit section?

Comment: It depends.  Is the _some text_ the actual label format with its own `^XA` and `^XZ` delimiters?  A typical label format starts with `^XA` and ends with `^XZ` and between those are all the formatting and data commands.  You can simply add `^LH0,100` right after the `^XA` if you want to include the offset in the format.  Or you can send `^XA^LH0,100^XZ` before sending the actual label format.

Comment: But the way i show in main post? Can u take a Look? If not how then should I do that in my currently code?

Comment: I have updated my response.  Can you please confirm that `some text` is actually a file path?

Comment: yes, my bad its path to file. So simply speaking in the file content at the beginning just add ^XA^LH0,100^XZ and then space and rest content?

Comment: This is great if you don't want to widen the margins. `^LH` doesn't support negative values.